# An Azure Cluster with Two Node Types

Tags: azure, cluster, kubernetes

I want to create a Kubernetes cluster on Azure with different node types. The cluster will be used for a web application that performs complex calculations. I want the web application to run on one type of nodes, and the calculations to run on different, much more capable, nodes.

I couldn't figure out how to create a cluster with two node types. I can create two clusters, but managing both of them and configuring their networks to work together can be a challenge.

Incidentally, I can move to AWS if that is supported there.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing support for multiple node pool types on AKS is expected end of October 2018, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/287)

However you can use ACS Engine to deploy an unmanaged Kubernetes cluster on Azure with multiple node pools.  See [here](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/README.md).

Amazon EKS does already support multiple node pools, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html).

As does GKS, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools)